# Records 1 Hour Before and 1 Hour After

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a set of trouble ticket data.  I would like to write a query that selects all the records in this table that have occurred from 1 hour before to 1 hour after a particular record was inserted.

Example:

Error "xyz" occurred at 2018-01-03 15:30:06.000
I would like to return EVERY trouble ticket that was created between 14:30:06.000 and 16:30:06.000 on 2018-01-03.  I would like this to happen for all occurrences of that error since the beginning of the year.

Is this possible?

This is what I have, considering the example provided below.  I'm still only returning the results in the temp table, and not the +1h and -1h of records from the *original* table.

select * into #temp
from Incident
where INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME > '01/01/2018'
and SUMMARY like '%error%'

select i.*
from Incident i
join #temp t on i.INCIDENT_ID = t.INCIDENT_ID
where i.INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(HH, -1, t.INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME)
and i.INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME < DATEADD(HH, 1, t.INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME)
order by i.INCIDENT_REPORTED_DATE_TIME

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please specify which RDBMs you mean, each DB has different functions for handling date/times

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: Sorry - totally new here.  MS SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ANSI SQL approach:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.col = 'xyz' and
        t.created >= t2.created - interval '1 hour' and
        t.created <= t2.created + interval '1 hour'
order by t.created;
```

Note that the exact syntax varies by database (which isn't specified as I write this).  But this idea should work in almost any database, with the right date/time functions.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.col = 'xyz' and
        t.created >= dateadd(hour, -1, t2.created) and
        t.created <= dateadd(hour 1, t2.created)
order by t.created;
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm fairly new, and am having difficulties.